# Open wifi DNS not working after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, 17.10

My room has this open wifi hotspot where you can openly connect and after that ask for a password (given by the building administration).

After upgrading to 17.10, I could connect to the wifi network, but after loading a bit (I could see this "loading" site from the building), a DNS error appears and I could not login or load any other site:

[Loading error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irrmw.png)

Yesterday added the google DNSs and at some point started to work (it took several reloads and tries), but today I couldn't make it work again (didn't change anything).

I have been trying different things I found about this, but until now there was no solution.

Creating and sharing a network from my phone (via wifi) seems to work, but nothing about this hotspot.

One thing I noticed was that everytime I start my computer, or restart network-manager, a hotspot is CREATED by ubuntu, so I need to stop it and select my network everytime.

NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

resolvconf

```
jack@jack-vision:~$ systemctl status resolvconf
● resolvconf.service - Nameserver information manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-10-25 11:48:42 CEST; 11min ago
     Docs: man:resolvconf(8)
  Process: 764 ExecStart=/sbin/resolvconf --enable-updates (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 763 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /run/resolvconf/postponed-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 759 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/resolvconf/interface (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 764 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/resolvconf.service

Oct 25 11:48:42 jack-vision systemd[1]: Starting Nameserver information manager...
Oct 25 11:48:42 jack-vision systemd[1]: Started Nameserver information manager.
Oct 25 11:48:42 jack-vision resolvconf[764]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

ping 8.8.8.8 did not work

```
jack@jack-vision:~$ sudo lshw -class network  
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 48
       serial: 60:57:18:82:87:7d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-16-lowlatency firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.49.173 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:34 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: enp4s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 80:fa:5b:14:df:71
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7814000-f7814fff memory:f7810000-f7813fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:41:e4:a1:d3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Let me know if there is more information needed for debugging.